# Dell XPS 13 7390, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Boxes: "Virtualization extensions are unavailable on your system

Tags: dell, virtualization, bios, gnome-boxes

I am trying to run Ubuntu 19.10 in a Boxes virtual machine on my Dell XPS 7390 running Ubuntu 18.04.4. Boxes is telling me that 'virtualization extensions are not available on my system', and that I should check the BIOS settings. However, all virtualization options on my laptop BIOS have been enabled. How could I solve this problem?

I don't know if this is an issue with my laptop, with Ubuntu, or with Boxes, so I'm not quite sure whether this is the right forum to ask. However, I also don't know where else to start.

Comment: How did you install Boxes? Are you running a 32- or 64-bit guests? How much RAM did you allocate to them?

Comment: @Kurankat Boxes came installed with my distribution (version 3.36.0), running 64 bit, 4GB RAM.

Comment: What is the version of your hosting operating system, i.e., on what system does Boxes run?

Comment: @vanadium Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Please add relevant information to your question (use "Edit") - I see now, it is in the title, but you better repeat it in the body of the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Ubuntu 20.04.5. Things actually started working after I issued

```bash
apt install qemu-system libvirt-daemon-system
```

which is the first command when following [KVM - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/KVM)'s chapter "installation". (I actually used the command with `--no-install-recommends`.)

Since I am running `gnome-boxes` as a non-root user I also added this non-root user to the group libvirt:

```bash
adduser <youruser> libvirt
```

I still see "Permission denied" errors from libvirtd in `/var/log/syslog` but Boxes let me create and run a VM.